# How to resolve "Skipped 31 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." for Android TCP Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, serversocket

I **need** to create an app that has an Android phone as a server, while the client (python) is on a linux system. I basically wish to send messages between the two, over wifi.

I have **no** app development (or JAVA) experience so I am looking into sample codes. I found the following, which basically displays whenever a client connects to the server.

But I get the warning message when I try to run this on an android emulator (android sdk)

> Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I haven't implemented the client side yet, but here is the code I am referring to. How do I improve upon this?
**Server.java**

```
package test.server2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Server {
    MainActivity activity;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String message = "";
    static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;

    public Server(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new     SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return socketServerPORT;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create ServerSocket using specified port
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    // block the call until connection is created and     return
                    // Socket object
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;
                    message += "#" + count + " from "
                            + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                            + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            activity.msg.setText(message);
                        }
                    });

                    SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread =
                            new SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count);
                    socketServerReplyThread.run();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        int cnt;

        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            cnt = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            String msgReply = "Hello from Server, you are #" + cnt;

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new     PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.close();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activity.msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activity.msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces =     NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                        .nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "Server running at : "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return ip;
    }
}
```

(Sorry about any incorrect indentation here, but the code above did work in the emulator)

And, **MainActivity.java**

```
package test.server2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Server server;
    TextView infoip, msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)     findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            }
        });

        infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        server = new Server(this);
        infoip.setText(server.getIpAddress() + ":" + server.getPort());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        server.onDestroy();


    }
}
```

Any insight on how the thread needs to be modified here?

I will be adding buttons and have server send messages to client and receive messages, so not skipping "frames" and such is important. It's also important to not having the app crash because the client is actually a robot.

Answer (score 0):

I have not run your code, however try to ommit the server.getIpAdress() call in the onCreate() method of your activity.

The getIpAdress() method is doing a lot of time consuming things like NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() and InetAdress.getHostAdress().

Look up mechanisms like AsyncTask for querying the Server object for an ipaddress in a background thread and updating the view with the result on the main thread.

Comment: I am still trying to learn through based on your suggestions. Will update as soon as I make progress. Thanks for your help.